How to add your own account on an existing tunnel？
Connected to an existing tunnel process running on this machine. You can press: "x" + Enter to stop the tunnel and exit "r" + Enter to restart the tunnel Ctrl+C to detach
There is already a remote tunnel established by others. How should I operate it? The official meaning is that a remote tunnel can only be used by one github account.
